# Pi closes ssh connection after successful login

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I left my pi sitting for a few days with a 3V relay & sensor connected. I just tried to ssh into it, and the connection is closed after a successful login:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.57-v7+ #1244 SMP Thu Jul 4 18:45:25 BST 2019 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Jul 24 05:07:08 2019 from 192.168.86.27
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.86.20 closed.
Transferred: sent 2152, received 2744 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 15562.4, received 19843.5
debug1: Exit status -1
```

I've tried the following (all of which return nothing after logging in):

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.lan mv .bash_profile .bash_profile.SAVE
```

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.lan mv .profile .profile.SAVE
```

Perhaps I should just reflash?

Comment: I think you're on the right track with trying to move those files. Something is likely causing the shell to fail to launch. If you got no error when moving those files, then explicit commands are likely working. Try logging in with `ssh ... bash`. You won't get a prompt or anything, as it'll launch a bare `bash` process. But should let you start poking around.